# Is the access source (IP or Domain name) of the webhook fixed?

Tags: webhooks, autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

I'm thinking of using a model-derived API on a network that isn't accessible from the outside.

To receive the conversion result with Webhook
I am thinking of allowing access from the outside only to the access source of the webhook, but please let me know because I do not know the access source information such as the IP address list of the webhook.

Answer (score 0):

The IP is not fixed for it. Instead of using IP based filtering to be assured that a call to the callback URL is coming from **Webhooks**, developers can verify the callback signature:
https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/webhooks/v1/tutorials/how-to-verify-payload-signature/

Comment: Thank you for your response.
I solved this problem by going through API Gateway.